# All images are gone after open a doc file created by libreoffice writer

Tags: libreoffice

I got a paper template in .doc format from a conference site. Now when i work on it with libreoffice and insert image to it and insert caption for the image, after closing the file and opening it again, all images are gone. I saw that when the image Anchor is set "to frame" the image will be gone but when it is set to e.g. "to paragraph" it will maintain but it's alignment will be corrupted. Also, i need the Anchor to be set to "Frame".

What can I do?

I searched the net but i didn't find a good answer.

Answer (score 8):

It seems you've hit one of those cases where LibreOffice barfs on .doc/.docx files and doesn't save some data.

Try this:

1. Save .doc template as .odt (OpenDocument) format
2. Edit the .odt.
3. After you've done editing save the .odt (it should save fine)
4. Save the file as .doc or .rtf.
5. If it still doesn't work, and you need to save the file as .doc, you'll have to open the .odt file in a computer with Microsoft Office 2010 and save it as .doc.

Keep in mind that LibreOffice is only guaranteed to work without issues with OpenDocument files (and maybe .pdf files), it still has issues when dealing with Microsoft Office files.

Answer (score 0):

Your image may actually be there. Try looking at the document via File -> Page Preview.

I have had the same problem. In Options > View I had display graphics turned on. I saved as .odt, but nothing helped. As long as you plan on printing the document anyway, don't worry that the document originating in a Microsoft product won't allow graphics to be viewed on the screen, as long as they print fine. (BTW: for me the graphics are visible in exported .pdf files too.)

I trust that the amazing coders of the LibreOffice project will be able to solve the incompatibility soon.

Answer (score 0):

When opening .docx and images are not shown, I used

- Save the file as .doc (Word 97/2003).
- close Libreoffice and Re-open the file.

Answer (score 0):

there are more issues about LibreOffice products and dissapearing images in them. One solution is to increase the memory size reserved for graphic objects in Options - Memory for cca 200 MB.

I'm a fan of LOO, but as in most works we do, it's good to have backup saves in different formats & computers, so keep the documents or presentations also in LOO and in M$ format too.

thumbs up & God bless

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here on Linux, apparently you have to enable the display of images. Tools --> Options --> LibreOffice Writer --> View --> Check the box next to "Graphics and Objects". That solved this for me.